# Subdominio apuntando a Iframe

Tags: javascript

Buenas tardes quisiera pedir de su ayuda tengo un servidor local que apunta a 1 ip publica, ahora vamos a meter una redundancia a ese servidor local, el cual ahora tendra 2 ip publicas de salida, bien en el HOSTING no esta alojado las ips publicas si no un codigo en IFRAME, sensillo pero hasta ahora bien, en este nuevo cambio debido a que si se cae ese servidor con la IP PUBLICA 1 el iframe detecte el cambio o si la persona intenta entrar y el IFRAME que apunta a la IP publica 1 cambie a la ip PUBLICA 2 si este detecta que no esta en Línea o algun metodo de script que cuando intenten entrar digamos a si subdominio.mipagina.com el IFRAME que tiene la ip publica 1 la detecta OFFLINE cambie al iframe 2 con la segunda IP Publica que se le colocara alguna manera de hacer este tipo de cambio en el que codigo detecte si esta en línea permanezca de forma normal sin embargo si la ve fuera de línea se cambie al codigo dos o a la segunda ip espero poderme explicar gracias por su atención.